# How to get page height using php?

Tags: php, jquery

I need code for get page height using php,please anybody help me.

Thanks

Comment: Format your question so that it is more readable.

Comment: you have used the best way to post a question on SO...

Comment: so the question is, assuming a page has more content than can be captured at one moment without scrolling, how to capture the whole page in its entirety as an image? I may be wrong... but I don't think that is possible. You can get the contents of the page as generated, however.

Comment: I can't see any possible reason you may want to do this in PHP, unless you want to re-design the whole browser functionality, evaluate the HTML and CSS that you have posted, make a wild guess on what display will the end-user have, and post a screenshot of your site, instead of the actual site, to protect your HTML. Short answer: Please don't.

Comment: Dont get demoralised. even with the downvotes and comments people are still trying to help. As you are new on SO, please read about SO, its policies and ethics. [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page is a good place to start. Also SO is a QA site, its not a debugging or code snippet search. Please so some research first and than ask if you don't understand something you found in your research and experiments.

Answer (score 2):

`PHP` is a server side scripting language and a browser page is a client-side resource. You are mixing two different things. There is no direct way to get page height or width using `PHP`. However, if you can use `JavaScript` to set a cookie with `page height` and read the same `cookie` from `PHP`, you might achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: or an ajax post to send the height to php running on server side.

Comment: Actually, his question makes sense. Suppose you won't render the HTML to the user's browser. You may want to print, and knowing the page height would be useful to set page size

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to get page `height` in `php`

You could do in `js` as,

```
var ww = $( window ).height(); // returns height of browser viewport
var ww = $( document ).height(); // returns height of HTML document,
```

You can pass this to your `php` file by `AJAX`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'phpfile.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { data : ww },
    success: function (result) {
        doSomethingWithResult(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this:

```
<?php
 if(!$_REQUEST['pageHeight']){
   echo "
     <script src="jquery url here"/>
     <script>
       function getPageHeight(){
         return (window).height();//or some other way
       }
       $(document).ready(function(){
         var url = location.href.split('?'); 
         location.href = 
                url[0]+'?'+(url[1]?url[1]+'&':'')+'pageHeight='+getPageHeight();
       })
     </script>";
     return;
  }
  echo $_REQUEST['pageHeight'];
?>
```

This would works, but very ugly, I hope you really don't need this.